# R Package installation on centOS 7 Server - http error

Tags: r, package, rstudio, centos7

I am struggling to get a package installation via "install.packages("packagename") working on a centOS server using the latest R-Release. The server was setup with R Studio Server Pro.

Internet access is working in general. Package download works also, but after the download, the final installation of the package fails with the following error code:

```
Error: 163:6: unexpected '/'
163: http:/
```

I already checked that no requests are blocked with our firewall/proxy. The installation fails from within R Studio, R sessions itself and with all users on the server. It also fails for the central library and the users personal libraries.

Do you have any ideas what the issue might be?

Thanks

Christoph